# asp.net - global.asax in asp.net 2.0 app

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

I created a global.asax file for an asp.net application. I run some code in the session_start method. The code does not get executed. Is there some type of procedure for using a global.asax file in asp.net 2.0?

I have the asax file itself and also a codebehind file.

Thank you!

**Edit:**
asax file:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="GrowUp.Global" %>
```

The code behind file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;
namespace Ligdol 
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Global.
/// </summary>
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    public Global()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }   

    protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application["HostName"] = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["HostName"];
        Application["counter"] = 1;
    }

    protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the count from the application variable
    int counter = int.Parse(Application["counter"].ToString());
    //Check if a cookie exists.
    if(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["ligdolVersion"] != null)
    {
        //If a cookie exists, we need to redirect the user to the respective site.
        if(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["ligdolVersion"].ToString() == "new")
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 302;
            Response.Status = "Moved temporarily";
            Response.Redirect("http://beta.ligdol.co.il");
            return;
        }
        else if(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["ligdolVersion"].ToString() == "old")
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    else if (counter == 40)
    {
        // If a cookie does not already exist,
        //we need to check if the user is to be allowed to continue to the old site
        //or be redirected to the new site.


        //Note in a file that a user was redirected, so we can get an estimate of how many are being redirected.
        System.IO.TextWriter tw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"redirect.log");
        tw.WriteLine("Redirected to new site.");
        tw.Close();
        // Reset counter.
        Application["counter"] = 1;
        //write cookie made to expire in 30 days, by then the experiment will be over (we hope!).
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("ligdolVersion");
        DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan tsSpan = new TimeSpan(30, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        cookie.Expires = dtNow + tsSpan;
        cookie.Value = "new";
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        Response.Redirect("http://beta.ligdol.co.il");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        System.IO.TextWriter tw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"redirect.log");
        tw.WriteLine("Redirected to old site.");
        tw.Close();
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("ligdolVersion");
        DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan tsSpan = new TimeSpan(30, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        cookie.Expires = dtNow + tsSpan;
        cookie.Value = "old";
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        return;
    }

    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Application_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    #region Web Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {    
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

Comment: could you please post code that you have tried ?

Comment: Sure. Sorry. I thought maybe there is some known issue with the global.asax file in asp.net 2.0. Code posted in original post.

Comment: Did you add break point in Global.asax and check ?

Comment: Localy it works. I hit the breakpoint and it goes through and saves the cookie and all. On the remote server, nothing happens.

Comment: @Elad Lachmi: Do you mean by "On the remote server, nothing happens." that you are unable to hit the break point but anyway the code is executed ??

Comment: Nope. I can not debug on the remote server, but I see the code is not running (since no one is being redirected) and no asp.net error is showing.

Comment: @Akram Shahda - I also tried writing a line to the file from the application_start method and it wasn't writen. I think the global.asax file is not being called at all. Maybe this is an issue with asp.net 2.0?

Comment: @Elad Lachmi: I am not aware of such issue if it exists... Are you sure you have published the right version .. also, try something simple, like using an application variable to count the sessions and show its value on your page ..

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with asp.net 2.0 - I've used the global.asax file many times with no problems. How are you deploying your site to the remote server? Is it a Website or a Web Application Project?

Comment: @Aristos: I guess it is the default namespace of the application ..

Comment: @Graham Clark - It is a website project. I deploy by simple copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the codebehind file. Once I put the code inline inside the asax file, it worked. This might be the only solution for old website projects.